# Order by Distance without near method using Ruby geocoder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-geocoder

Is there a way to NOT limit the distance to the target position and only order by distance?

I'm currently doing something like this:

```
@positions = Position.near(@user_position.coordinates, 999999).order(:distance).paginate(page: params[:page])
```

But as a programmer, It feels not right to use something like this.

It would be great if there exists something like:

```
@positions = Position.near(@user_position.coordinates, :no_limit).order(:distance).paginate(page: params[:page])
```

I hope somebody can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not as unfriendly to programmer as it seems. If you worked with C, for example, you know that there is no exact definition of range of `int`. Even for Java, where the size is precise, it's still limited and you should not forget about it.

If you want you query be more readable, define `NO_LIMIT = 999999` constant and use it in place of `:no_limit`.

There is an answer from creator of `geocoder` on [similar issue](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder/issues/394):

> I think your best bet is to use a very large radius.

So there are probably no way around it.